# CMake third party dependency cannot compile OpenCV, unable to locate file which does exist

Tags: cmake

I'm using cmake on a c++ project which will be used in a mobile app, so I needed to put all the third party code into a folder in my source tree like so:

./third_party/opencv/ (<- this repo contents are here https://github.com/opencv/opencv)

The rest of my application code is at ./

I have a CMakeLists.txt mostly working, it starts processing the opencv code:

```
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/opencv/modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib3d.dir/src/undistort.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/opencv/modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib3d.dir/src/upnp.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/opencv/modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib3d.dir/opencl_kernels_calib3d.cpp.o
[ 35%] Building CXX object third_party/opencv/modules/calib3d/CMakeFiles/opencv_calib3d.dir/src/undistort.avx2.cpp.o
```

However then this happens, opencv cannot find a file which within that third_party directory:

```
[ 36%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_calib3d.so
[ 36%] Built target opencv_calib3d
Scanning dependencies of target run_tests
[ 36%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/run_tests.dir/tests/tests.cpp.o
In file included from /root/repo/third_party/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54,
                 from /root/repo/third_party/opencv/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp:46,
                 from /root/repo/tests/../third_party/opencv/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp:48,
                 from /root/repo/tests/tests.cpp:7:
/root/repo/third_party/opencv/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:52:10: fatal error: opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp: No such file or directory
 #include "opencv2/opencv_modules.hpp"
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/run_tests.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/run_tests.dir/tests/tests.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/run_tests.dir/tests/tests.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:79: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/run_tests.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/run_tests.dir/all] Error 2
```

The ./tests/tests.cpp mentioned in the error has the following includes:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unordered_set>
#include <vector>
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "../third_party/opencv/modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include "../third_party/opencv/modules/highgui/include/opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "../third_party/opencv/modules/videoio/include/opencv2/videoio.hpp"
#include "../video_processing.hpp"
#include "../hashing.hpp"
#include "../utils.hpp"
```

I do see that the opencv_modules.hpp it's complaining about doesn't actually exist, but this file does https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/cmake/templates/opencv_modules.hpp.in.

However I'm new to C++ and CMake so I've no idea what that is or how to create the hpp file from it.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(root)

find_program(CCACHE_FOUND ccache)
if(CCACHE_FOUND)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_COMPILE ccache)
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY RULE_LAUNCH_LINK ccache)
endif(CCACHE_FOUND)

find_package(ZXing CONFIG)

# Locate GTest
find_package(GTest REQUIRED)
include_directories(${GTEST_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_subdirectory(third_party)

add_executable(application ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/main.cpp)
add_executable(run_tests ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/tests/tests.cpp)

set(LINK_LIBS ${GTEST_LIBRARIES} pthread ${ZBAR_LIBRARIES} ZXingCore opencv_core opencv_imgcodecs opencv_imgproc opencv_features2d opencv_calib3d opencv_videoio)
target_link_libraries(application ${LINK_LIBS})
target_link_libraries(run_tests ${LINK_LIBS})

file(GLOB OPENCV_MODULE_INCLUDE_DIRS third_party/opencv/include third_party/opencv/modules/*/include )

target_include_directories(application PUBLIC ${OPENCV_MODULE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(run_tests PUBLIC ${OPENCV_MODULE_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Can anyone spot a problem perhaps in the CMakeLists.txt which is causing OpenCV to fail include its own files?

Comment: "so I've no idea what that is or how to create the hpp file from it." - The file `opencv_modules.hpp` is created by OpenCV itself during configuration process. You may find that file in the build directory of your project under `opencv2/`. Note, this path lacks for `third_party/opencv/` component. It is because OpenCV is **not intended to work** when included with `add_subdirectory`. It is omitted by many blogs and "tutorials" which suggest use `add_subdirectory` for third-party projects: many third-party projects simply doesn't work with that approach.

Comment: Intended way to use OpenCV in CMake is `find_package(OpenCV)`. For make this work, you need to **install** OpenCV first.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I see, so how do I achieve that using CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: Do you want to install OpenCV inside your `CMakeLists.txt`? You may run any shell command on the configuration stage with [execute_process](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/execute_process.html). Just find which commands are needed for install OpenCV from the command line, and put every such command into its own `execute_process`. You may specify custom installation directory for OpenCV. In that case you need to add this directory to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` variable before calling `find_package(OpenCV)`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev  Most opencv install shell scripts include a bunch of "apt-get". I cannot do this, I need this to build for iOS

Comment: I don't mean to use ready-made scripts which installs OpenCV and all its prerequisites. There is common CMake-way for build and install packages `mkdir build`, `cd build`, `cmake ..` , `make`, `make install`. Note that you probably need to pass OpenCV-specific configuration options to `cmake`. And instead of `cd build` there is `WORKING_DIRECTORY` parameter to `execute_process`.

Comment: Note, that your intention to install OpenCV **automatically** (in your project) can also inconvenient for some users of your package in the same way as 'bunch of "apt-get"' in OpenCV installation scripts is inconvenient for you. More natural way is to leave installation of OpenCV to the user.

Comment: ok ill do that.